# Memory leak: HttpClient PostAsync with ByteArrayContent

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, httpclient

We have a memory leak in a seemingly simple `HttpClient` usage. We use Autofac to inject a single instance of `HttpClient` that is created like this:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => true;
httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
httpClient.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;    
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true; // load-balancer...
builder.RegisterInstance(httpClient).As<HttpClient>();
```

And the code that makes the `PostAsync` call:

```
using(var content = PrepareHttpContentJson(input))
using (HttpResponseMessage result = await _client.PostAsync(fullUrl, content))
{
  // do something with the result, but nothing is returned, i.e. no
  // references are returned to any objects from HttpResponseMessage.
  // Only result.IsSuccessStatusCode is checked.
}
```

And `PrepareHttpContentJson` basically converts serializes some object to JSON:

```
private static HttpContent PrepareHttpContentJson(object item)
{
  var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
  var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myContent);
  var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
  byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
  return byteContent;
}
```

This setup keeps leaking the ByteArrayContent objects (discovered using the debugger on a running process). The objects pointing to the ByteArrayContent are these:

```
HttpRequestMessage
Action<Stream>
HttpContentHeaders
```

For those unaware of the feature, Visual Studio Diagnostic Tools provides a way to analyse a running process for cpu and memory usage. Taking a memory snap shot lets you see detailed information about managed memory, like type of memory (`System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent` in my case), size, and content (though cumbersome for byte arrays). If also shows reference count and which objects point to it. Taking a snapshot more and VS can show the difference in memory allocated, also very detailed. This is how I know the objects leaked are ByteArrayContent and I have verified the content and there know the shown code is the one leaking it.

Edit:

I had a look at the implementation of PostAsync in HttpClient and found this node in the cleanup section:

```
    private void HandleFinishSendAsyncCleanup(CancellationTokenSource cts, bool disposeCts)
    {
        // Dispose of the CancellationTokenSource if it was created specially for this request
        // rather than being used across multiple requests.
        if (disposeCts)
        {
            cts.Dispose();
        }

        // This method used to also dispose of the request content, e.g.:
        //     request.Content?.Dispose();
        // This has multiple problems:
        // 1. It prevents code from reusing request content objects for subsequent requests,
        //    as disposing of the object likely invalidates it for further use.
        // 2. It prevents the possibility of partial or full duplex communication, even if supported
        //    by the handler, as the request content may still be in use even if the response
        //    (or response headers) has been received.
        // By changing this to not dispose of the request content, disposal may end up being
        // left for the finalizer to handle, or the developer can explicitly dispose of the
        // content when they're done with it.  But it allows request content to be reused,
        // and more importantly it enables handlers that allow receiving of the response before
        // fully sending the request.  Prior to this change, a handler like CurlHandler would
        // fail trying to access certain sites, if the site sent its response before it had
        // completely received the request: CurlHandler might then find that the request content
        // was disposed of while it still needed to read from it.
    }
```

The user must now handle Dispose. But even though I dispose the `ByteArrayContent`, the memory still leaks. I'll try with a `result.Content = null` as well.

Edit:

I have now replaced the `PostAsync` code with this:

```
    using (var content = PrepareHttpContentJson(input))
    using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(fullUrl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)))
    {
      request.Content = content;
      using (HttpResponseMessage result = await _client.SendAsync(request, CancellationToken.None))
      {
        // do something with the result before cleanup
        result.Content?.Dispose();
        result.Content = null;
      }
      request.Content?.Dispose();
      request.Content = null;
    }
```

Doing this has helped slightly in that there are now "just" two objects having a link to the ByteArrayContent object:

```
Action<Stream>
HttpContentHeaders
```

i.e. `HttpRequestMessage` is now properly disposed and does not have a link to `ByteArrayContent`. I'll have to hunt down other objects I can dispose in this quest.

Comment: I haven't tried yet, but the leak is real enough as Windows keeps killing processes due to lack of memory. And I know the actual leak in the managed memory is of type System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent that wont be garbage collected because of 3 references to them from HttpRequestMessage, Action<Stream>, and HttpContentHeaders.

Comment: I haven't tried forcing `GC.Collect` and the memory lost is every single ByteArrayContent sent which amounts to several hundred MB daily (and will only increase in the future). I know the type of memory leaked as I take a snapshot of the memory usage using Visual Studio and it shows all memory allocated including the type of memory and the size. The VS Diagnostic Tools provide this function and lets you make detailed memory analysis.

Comment: I thought that was a minor detail, but I'll edit the question to reflect this. Other people may be unaware of this feature and it is really helpful for memory leak discovery. The code is running Release mode, but I am using the remote debugger and as such do not have a similar compiled binary locally. This should not matter as all I look for is memory leaks and the remote debugging lets me analyse the remote memory using my local visual studio.

Comment: The `PostAsync` method is in a method that is in a class that has a constructor that takes `HttpClient` as argument and that `HttpClient` is turned into a `_client` class variable. That class is instantiated by Autofac that provides the `HttpClient` from the first code section. There can be multiple parallel invocations of the method, but as `HttpClient`is thread safe, this should not be an issue.

Comment: Cool - a [mcve] will be crucial given the number of moving parts.

Comment: Thanks. You could have started with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing `CancellationToken.None` with your own token makes the leak go away. Add this line before the first using:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
using(var content = PrepareHttpContentJson(...
```

and use `cts.Token` instead of `CancellationToken.None` makes the memory leak stop.

There may be a bug in HttpClient that can cause this memory leak, or at least an interaction effect with Autofac, but that seems less likely.

Comment: I was able to reach this conclusion myself today after battling this leak for days. Did you ever end up taking a look at the source to see if its a legit bug?

Comment: No. I did not have the time for that.